# How to read directelly the last charachter in a string in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following string

```
string="anyanyanay"
```

How I can read the last charachter in the string?

Comment: `echo $string | sed -E 's/(.*)(.)$/\2/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Below Script

```
#!/bin/bash
string="anyanyanay"
echo ${string#${string%?}}
```

Output :
    `y`

`${string%?}` removes last character from string.

`${string#<character>}` removes `characters` from string starting.

In this case

`${string%?} = anyanyana`

`${string#${string%?}} = ${string#anyanyana} = y`

Answer (score 4):

Pure BASH:

```
last="${string:(-1):1}"
```

OR:

```
[[ "$string" =~ (.)$ ]] && last="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "$last"
y
```

Using sed:

```
last=$(sed 's/^.*\(.\)$/\1/' <<< "$string")
echo "$last"
y
```

Using awk:

```
awk -F'\0' '{print $NF}' <<< "$string"
y
```

Comment: +1 very complete! I also thought about `echo "$string" | rev | cut -c1`

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui For completeness sake just when I was going to add `grep` in my answer I saw Kent had posted same so I avoided posting it :)

Comment: I am sure there are other ways but my personal favorite is `"${string:(-1):1}"` since is smallest, simplest and done in a single operation. Unfortunately OP didn't go for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

```
kent$  echo "anyanyanay"|grep -o '.$'
y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $string | sed -E 's/(.*)(.)$/\2/'
```

or

```
echo $string | tail -c 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
echo $string|sed 's/.*\(.\)$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative indices to get the characters in the reverse order. -1 is the last, -2 is the second last and so on

echo $string[-1]

Comment: Have you tried it? It just returns `anyanyanay[-1]`